# Using Object instead of Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

i'm not good at using objects. And i'm working on using objects instead of arrays.

I have a code as array

```
$jsonData['overstockid'][] = $productid;
```

How can i write this as object ?

I defined jsonData

```
$jsonData = new \stdClass();
```

i know i can write `$jsonData->overstockid`

Comment: First of all you need a class for your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `overstockid` property to an array, and then add to it:

```
$jsonData->overstockid = array();
$jsonData->overstockid[] = $productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick but nasty workaround to convert an `array` to an `object` is to use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.

#### Example

```
$array = array(
    'id' => 123,
    'sub_id' => 456,
    'gender' => 1,
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => 960,
);

$object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

Hope this helps.